# Back Button Issues With Navigation Controller (iPhone)

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

So here's the functionality that I'm looking for:
1. Main Menu doesn't have the navigation Bar
2. All other screens from the Main Menu do.
3. It should animate correctly

I partially got this to work (just not the back button part).

In the Main Menu viewDidLoad I just go:

```
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];
```

In another window (Screen1), in its viewDidLoad I go:

```
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES];
```

So now, when I run the program. I have my own button in the main menu that when you click it, it transitions to Screen1, and the animation works properly: I.e., no bar in main menu but and as soon as I hit the button, Screen1 slides in with its Navigation Controller Bar. So far so good.

But here's the problem, when I click the "back" button to go back to my Main Menu from Screen1 it keeps the Navigation Controller Bar up there (i.e., it doesn't call the Main Menu's viewDidLoad) but I don't want a Bar in my main menu! Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use `viewDidLoad`, use `viewWillAppear:` or `viewDidAppear:` (depending on which looks better for you). `viewDidLoad` is only called once, the first time the view loads.

Comment: thank you, that did it (I used viewWillAppear in main menu to set the 
navigation bar to hidden)

Answer (score 1):

What if you try hiding it in `viewDidAppear` instead of `viewDidLoad`?